# Marginal distribution from joint distribution

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution, marginal-distribution

I have the joint distribution of two random variables $x,\theta$
$$h(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left[(x-\theta)^2+\frac{\theta^2}{\sigma^2}\right]\right\}$$
To find the marginal distribution of $x$, I need to integrate this over all possible values of $\theta$, so that
$$m(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left[(x-\theta)^2+\frac{\theta^2}{\sigma^2}\right]\right\}d\theta$$
I am kinda confused how to proceed from here, I'm sure there is some minor transformation that needs to be done but it is not clicking. Hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Write $(x-\theta)^2+\frac{\theta^2}{\sigma^2}$ in the form $c(\theta -a)^{2}+b^{2}$ and use normal density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Start writing
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\left[(x-\theta)^2+\frac{\theta^2}{\sigma^2}\right]=\frac{1}{2}  \left(1+\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}\right)\theta ^2- x\,\theta+\frac{x^2}2 $$ Complete the square and use a clear substitution.

Yous should face a very simple integral and result